# How can I remove empty space from the beginning of strings but inside some HTML tags using PHP?

Tags: php, html, preg-replace, str-replace, trim

Say I have this:

```
<p>  This is a paragraph.</p><p>&nbsp;This is another paragraph.</p>
```

I want it to be:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p><p>This is another paragraph.</p>
```

I cannot simply use `trim()` as there is the `<p>` at the beginning. But I also can't use the `str_replace()`/`preg_replace()` as I need to retain the empty space inside `This is a paragraph`. How should I achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: How are you building this HTML in the first place?

Comment: The HTML is from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex bellow:

```
(?<=>)(\s|&nbsp;)*|(\s|&nbsp;)*(?=<\/)
```

https://regex101.com/r/fZ3oQ3/2

PHP Code example:

```
$re = "/(?<=>)(\\s|&nbsp;)*|(\\s|&nbsp;)*(?=<\\/)/"; 
$str = "<p>  This is a paragraph.</p><p>&nbsp;This is another paragraph.</p>\n"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: great! But in my situation, my empty space could be the an empty space in Chinese ("　") (sorry I don't know how to type it.) How to include it also in the regex?  Thanks!

Comment: For unicode it's possible to use `\p{Z}` or `\p{Separator}` which match any kind of whitespace or invisible separator. Try: `$re = "/(?<=>)(\\p{Z}|&nbsp;)*|(\\p{Z}|&nbsp;)*(?=<\\/)/u";`